# JSON unexpected token in Slim.php

Tags: javascript, php, json, slim

I have this simple JSON request

```
var jsonObject = {apiKey:'123123',method:'asdfsadfasdf',ip:'123.232.123.12'};

$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.example.com/users/add",
    type: "POST",
    data: jsonObject,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        switch (result) {
            case true:
                alert(result);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

posting to a slim API

```
$app->post('/add', function () use ($app) {
    $user =  $app->request->post() ;
    $ip = $user['ip'];
    $method = $user['method'];
    $apiKey = $user['apiKey'];
});
```

however the alert in the javascript shows 123123 when I return apiKey but other 2 parameters show 'Unexpected token' even though the response in Chrome console shows the correct value.

Comment: What response are you sending back?

Comment: If I echo ip I get the IP, if I echo method I get method so the response is correct. I am just wondering why JSON would complain with a 200 error that there is an unexpected token. If I echo apiKey I get no error.

Comment: You have to use `JSON.stringify()` to convert the object to JSON string, as the `data` parameter supportd PlainObject or String or Array according to http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `dataType` setting in `$.ajax`, you are expecting that the response from the server should be a `json` valid string. From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript
>   object. [...] The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any
>   malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown.

It seems like that you want to return back your parameters. To do that just print data in the right way (encode it in JSON):

```
$app->post('/users/add', function () use ($app) {
    $user =  $app->request->post() ;
    $ip = $user['ip'];
    $method = $user['method'];
    $apiKey = $user['apiKey'];
    echo json_encode($user);
});
```

Now you can access to that data using the `result` parameter of `success` `$.ajax` callback.

### Ok, but I want to print data in my own way

If you want you could also print strings directly, using double quotes:

```
echo "\"$method\"";
```

your json parse will work correctly now.

Numbers (e.g. `apiKey`) work without issues because they are numbers and they don't need double quotes.

Further reading: [JSON.parse() documentation of MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).